# Django Model count in Foreign key

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Position(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Is there a way that i can count how many positions are there in this kind of Person model? Like Person.position.count..some sort of this. Please help me. This is counting inside model only. please.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, if you have a `Person` instance with name `person`, you can use `person.position_set.count()`.

Comment: Can you use this in your template?

Answer (score 1):

No matter, if you are trying to get the count of all objects or from the set of foreign key as @MostafaR suggested. You should use the `.count()` method on querysets. Also make sure you do not use `len()` if all you are looking for is the count and not the objects as `len()` method will evaluate the queryset. [More information here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

#### To get the count of all objects

```
models.Position.objects.all.count()
```

#### To get the count of objects using foreign key

```
person = models.Person.objects.get(pk=1, **kwargs)
person.position_set.count()
```

Comment: I'm making a `@property` to my model. Is this possible `@property` `def count(self):` `return self.Position.count()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method in Person model

```
class Person(models.Model):
 # ...
     def position(self):
         return self.position_set.count()
```